# How to Create Extension Package in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, extensions, magento-connect

In Magento 1.x we are **creating Extension Package** from `System` -> `Magento Connect` -> `Package Extensions`. After that we are going to publish the extension in Magento Connect.

I think it's an easy to understand and easy to create and publish.

In Magento 2.x how to create like above and publish the extension to MarketPlace (Magento Connect).

Could you please suggest me how to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's say you have developped a module under `app/code/Vendor/Module`, here is the procedure you have to follow:

### Create a composer file

Go to `app/code/Vendor/Module` and create the following `composer.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "vendor/module",
  "description": "Description of your Magento 2 module",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
    "magento/framework": "~100.0.4"
  },
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Firstname Lastname",
      "email": "email@address.com",
      "homepage": "https://www.store.com/",
      "role": "Developer"
    }
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Vendor\\Module\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

### Zip the package

Using command line do the following:

```
cd /path/to/app/code/Vendor/Module
zip -r vendor_module-0.1.0.zip ./*
```

N.B.: this example is assuming that your module version (declared under `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml` is 0.1.0, please change the version in both the `composer.json` and in the command that zips the package to match your version.

Comment: What to do if this module depends on other one?

Comment: I have to create package for two 'magento2-module' type. How i can do this?

Answer (score 5):

To create extension package and how to publish it, check following source :

1. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/package/package_module.html
2. http://docs.magento.com/marketplace/user_guide/getting-started.html

Hope it helps

Comment: we are a partner of Magento. we have completed the extension, now ready to upload. The below link shows the options is under My Account. http://docs.magento.com/marketplace/user_guide/extensions/extension-submit.html, but I can't find any options to upload extension. Can you please guide me how to do it?