# magento 2 How to create package of your custom module?

Tags: magento-2.1

I reviewed the suggestion here 
[How to Create Extension Package in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105533/how-to-create-extension-package-in-magento-2)
but I am still getting issue:-
The "composer.json" file has incorrect JSON; please verify the archive.
my composer.json is as below

```
{
  "name": "Vendorname/Modulename",
  "description": "Magento 2 Qrcode Generator",
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
  },
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
  ],
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "w3solver",
      "email": "query@w3solver.com",
      "homepage": "https://www.w3solver.com",
      "role": "developer"
    }
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Vendorname\\Modulename\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

I zipped my folder by name vendorname_modulename-1.0.1, my version is 1.0.1 in module.xml. I created zipped from 'modulename'

I am not getting what is wrong with my composer.json

Answer (score 0):

Try this composer.json

```
    {
        "name": "vendorname/module-modulename",
        "description": "",
        "license": "proprietary",
        "authors": [
            {
                "name": "w3solver",
                "email": "query@w3solver.com"
            },
            {
                "name": "Your Name",
                "email": "email@email.com"
            }
        ],
        "minimum-stability": "dev",
        "require": {},
        "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
                "Vendorname\\Modulename\\": ""
            },
            "files": [
                "registration.php"
            ]
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. You added "," after last value, for example :

```
"require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
  },
```

it should be  :

```
"require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0"
  },
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
{
  "name": "Vendorname/Modulename",
  "description": "Magento 2 Qrcode Generator",
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0"
  },
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "proprietary"
  ],
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "w3solver",
      "email": "query@w3solver.com",
      "homepage": "https://www.w3solver.com",
      "role": "developer"
    }
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Vendorname\\Modulename\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what was exactly the issue, but I resolved it by following below composer @prince thanks for your effort to provide an answer

```
    {
    "name": "vendorname/modulename",
    "description": "extension",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "w3solver",
            "email": "query@w3solver.com",
            "homepage": "http://www.w3solver.com"
        }
    ],
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Vendorname\\Modulename\\": ""
        }
    },
    "keywords": [
        "magento2",
        "magento 2",
        "qrcode",
        "qrcode generator"
    ]
}
```